# How to run init.d script directly?

Tags: init.d, systemd

I'm trying to run `/etc/init.d/mydaemon status` but the `systemd` gets in the way with its own wrong status that can rely on pid files in case of SysV scripts (that init.d script uses no pid files).

How it's doing that and what is a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Build an upstart job, it can probably solve your problem. It worked for me. You can achieve that as follows :

Create      `/etc/init/myjob.conf`

Add the following entries to the file

```
description "my Job"
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/my/script.sh
```

This is just an example. You can give whatever name you want, and the path leading to your script.

Comment: How do you propose that the upstart job be run on the questioner's systemd operating system?

Comment: I guess upstart job will run on system startup, so by putting the job in the init directory should execute the job.

Comment: @Bidyut, it's not about startup at all.